# How to work with azure devops default service principal for keyvault variable group expansion in terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I'm using terraform to create a project. The project puts a pipeline and variable group in place. The variable group is pulling its secrets from keyvault. This is not happening inside a pipeline, since there is no project yet. The process of connecting to keyvault in order to inject secrets into the var group requires a keyvault access policy. Devops appears to create 2 application registrations per project, named for the project. One of these identities is the spn that is used to reach out to keyvault and therefore is the spn oid that should be put in the access policy.

I can't seem to pull this spn dynamically at run time, so the apply fails on first run complaining with this error:

```
│ Error: Expanding variable group resource data: Failed to get the Azure Key valut.  Erroe: ( code: forbidden, messge: Failed to query service connection API: 'https://mykv.vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=2016-10-01'. Status Code: 'Forbidden', Response from server: '{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"The user, group or application 'appid=xxxxxxxx;oid=xxxxxxxx;iss=https://sts.windows.net/<uuid>/' does not have secrets list permission on key vault 'mykv;location=uksouth'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287","innererror":{"code":"AccessDenied"}}}' )
```

This is because the access policy doesn't have the oid of the app reg of devops, for the project that was just created. I've tried creating my own spn and adding that, but variable group expansion seems to only want to use the default spns. No tf resource exports this data, so I either need to manually paste in the oid to the access policy returned by the error when it fails, and then it works no problem, or I need to know the spn name to pull it with a data block which is <project_name>-uid and I don't think I can predict the uid.

Does anyone have any experience in dealing with these default app regs? Do I have to use this app reg or can I pull the default app reg with fuzzy naming rather than having to know the uid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each service connection you create in azure devops a corresponding azure ad enterprise application is created. The user that creates these service connection needs to have the built in "Application Developer" ad role or "Application Administrator" or some custom role that satisfies these requirements.

When you create a service connection at the subscription scope named "myconnection" on the backend in azure ad an enterprise application called "<orgname>-<projectname>-<subscirptionid>" is created.

`azuredevops_variable_group` can link to a keyvault using a service connection to pull in secret values. The identity used to access the keyvault is the oid of the enterprise application that sits behind the service connection.

```
resource "azuredevops_variable_group" "credentials" {
  project_id = var.id
  name = var.name
  description = var.descr
  allow_access = true
  
  key_vault {
    name = var.keyvault_name
    service_endpoint_id = azuredevops_serviceendpiont_azurerm.deploy.id
  }

  variable {
    name = "supersecret" // secret name that sits in the keyvault
  }
...
  depends_on = [azurerm_role_assignment.kv]
}
```

This means we have to look up the enterprise app for the service connection and allow read via role assignment in an rbac enabled azure keyvault. I've done this as part of a loop but this example removes the loop. Also you could easily hardcode some of these steps but this does it dynamically for my requirements.

Fetch the metadata about the service connection of which we're interested in the subscription id.

```
data "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "deploy" {
    project_id = var.project_id
    service_endpoint_name = azuredevops_serviceendpiont_azurerm.deploy.service_endpoint_name
}
```

Then fetch the app at the backend of the sconn. There are many various ids used in an app reg and if you do something like `az ad sp show --id <appregid>` the one you want shows up under just "id" you might be tempted to use `azuread_application` data block to get this by `id` or `object_id` but it's not actually exposed in that resource, you have to use `azuread_service_principal`

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "sp" {
  display_name = "<orgname>-<projectname>-${data.azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.deploy.azurerm_subscription_id}"
}
```

Then create the role assignment for the application - you may be tempted to use "Key Vault Reader" here this is wrong, the variable group can only authenitcate when Secrets User is used on an rbac enabled kv. The equivalent to this for non-rbac enabled kvs is an access policy with this principal id which has "List,Get" permissions.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "kv" {
   scope = data.azurerm_resource_group.id
   role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
   principal_id = data.azuread_service_principal.sp.id

   depends_on = [azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.deploy]
}
```

It's important to note that this can easily break. When you create multiple service connections for a subscription - during the natural development plan apply process or when testing - the data lookup block will fail saying it's found multiple applications. The enterprise app names don't conflict, they're arbitrary so looking them up can be a pain. For my requirements I have 1 service connection per subscription, if you have multiple you may need a better lookup criteria than just the name.

If you end up with duplicate names, just delete the ones that aren't in use.